# How to handle relationships in Room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm testing Room persistence library. I have two `entity` classes:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @PrimaryKey
   int id;
   String name;
}

@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
                                  parentColumns = "id",
                                  childColumns = "userId")
public class Pet {
   @PrimaryKey
   int id;
   String name;
   int userId;       
}
```

Now I'd like to get list of Pet and in each `Pet` object keep actual reference to `User` according to his `userId`. So each time when the `userId` is changed, this reference also should be changed. Is it possible to do? Or maybe there is a better way to handle relation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ROOM not recommended to do that. The reasons are in the reference link.

Maybe you could try it,

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @PrimaryKey
   int id;
   String name;
   @Embedded
   public List<Pet> userPet;
}

public class Pet {
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

[Understand why Room doesn't allow object references](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data.html#understand-no-object-references)

[A convenience annotation which can be used in a Pojo to automatically fetch relation entities.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html)

Comment: I'm not sure why Room doesn't handle object references... Core Data on iOS has no such problem. The reasons given in "Understand why Room doesn't allow object references" doesn't make sense and sounds like a lazy implementation of Room by Google.

Comment: You cannot embed a **list of object**. Either you have to use `@typeconverters` or `@Relation`

Comment: Yes,  @tahsinRupam is right,  annotation Embedded work for single object. As for list, I recommemed to use annotation Relation. e.g.    @Relation(parentColumn = "parent_id", entityColumn = "child_id", entity = Child.class) public List<Child> childPet;